# iOS: Bundle Display Name

Tags: ios, cfbundledisplayname

I have a strange behavior with the bundle display name of my App. If I set the BundleDisplayName to "Foo.App" (My App must contain the .App in the name) then the App is called: "Foo.App.app".

And if I add a blank space "Foo.App " to the bundle display name then it looks ok on the homescreen. But the workaround gets visible when the app asks to turn on access the location "Allow "SEF.App " to access..."

Can somebody tell me where the additional ".app" comes from?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why does it happen. But I found a workaround: write "App" with Russian letter "А". You can copy it from this answer.

[image]